# Bash script in linux server not work to set permission to a file

Tags: linux, bash

I write the code in a .sh file and run it...

```
 die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}


[ "$#" -eq 2 ] || die "2 argument required, $# provided"
echo $2 | grep -E -q '^[0-9]+$' || die "Numeric argument required, $2 provided"


nfile_location = /home/virtual/$1

if [ -f $nfile_location ];
then
    chmod -R $2 $nfile_location
    echo "Set permission";
    exit 1;
else
    echo "Not a correct file";
    exit 1;
fi
```

but it is not working. it shows the following error, which i can not understant as i am new in bash scripting.

```
/root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh: line 11: nfile_location: command not found
chmod: missing operand after `777'
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
Set permission
```

Comment: If this is bash and not a POSIX shell, such as dash, you can do a regex match on $2 without the pipeline and grep.

`[[ $2 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || die "Numeric argument required, $2 provided"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There must be no spaces before or after the `=` sign.

Wrong: `nfile_location = /home/virtual/$1`

Correct: `nfile_location=/home/virtual/$1`